# Matching rows based on ID column, comparing another column, returning value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet of orders, and I am trying to compare stock status of each order to determine if the order is shippable or not. I'm not sure if it is possible with an Excel formula, maybe I need to write a macro, but here is a sample set of data:

| ID | Stock Status | Order Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | In Stock | Shippable |
| 1 | In Stock |  |
| 1 | Out of Stock |  |
| 1 | Shipped |  |
| 1 | Shipped |  |
| 1 | Shipped |  |
| 2 | Out of Stock | Shippable but contains OOS Items |
| 2 | In Stock |  |
| 2 | In Stock |  |
| 3 | In Stock | Shippable |
| 3 | Shipped |  |
| 3 | Shipped |  |
| 4 | Out of Stock | Not Shippable |
| 5 | In Stock | Not Shippable |
| 5 | Out of Stock |  |
| 5 | Out of Stock |  |
| 5 | Shipped |  |
| 5 | Shipped |  |

I want to compare stock status (Column B), excluding "Shipped" values, for each order (Column A). I want to return a value in Column C based on three possible outcomes (example is populated with values):

- All stock status "In Stock" = Shippable (example ID 3)
- More than 50% stock status "In Stock" = Shippable but contains OOS Items (example ID 2)
- Less than 50% stock status "In Stock" = Not Shippable (example ID 5)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I deleted my initial question since I forgot to add a scenario with partially fulfilled orders, but a very helpful person posted this formula that almost gets me there, I just need to exclude the "Shipped" values:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,CHOOSE(MATCH(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"In Stock")/COUNTIFS(A:A,A2),{0,0.5,1}),"Not Shippable","Shippable but contains OOS","Shippable"),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

just change `COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)` to `COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>Shipped")`

```
=IF(A1<>A2,CHOOSE(MATCH(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"In Stock")/COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>Shipped"),{0,0.5,1}),"Not Shippable","Shippable but contains OOS","Shippable"),"")
```

[image]